# How to export file from android to network computer, connected through LAN

Tags: java, android

I have developed an android application which is connected through LAN. In my application whatever the data scanned, all that data should export in excel on the desired network PC.
Is there any way to send the data using LAN?

if any one has the related solution, please provide the code, link or any other solution which would be appreciated.

Comment: you will have to develop a server-side application for you PC, which will accept the file you want to send. After that you can send it

Comment: There are very many ways. Perhapse you should spend some time on Google reading tutorials for networking in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I found that link that could help you, it even provides a full example code in JAVA : 
[JAVA Simple File Tranfer over LAN](http://thegeekyway.com/filetransfer/)

But as others pointed right, you should spend some time on Google, and find a code example to have a start. Then come back with your code when something is not working.